# Check if wallet is encrypted or not through RPC API

Tags: wallet, bitcoind, api, json-rpc, encryption

How can one check if their wallet is encrypted through the RPC API without receiving an exception?

I went through the [Original Bitcoin client API calls list](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list) but didn't find any command that could facilitate this functionality without resulting into an error in the response.

Any ideas or workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the source code](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/rpcprotocol.h#L34) (`rpcprotocol.h`):

```
RPC_WALLET_ERROR                = -4,  // Unspecified problem with wallet (key not found etc.)
```

So you could check for a JSON-RPC return value of `-4`, or if you want to be absolutely sure, you can use:

```
bitcoind [...] -help | grep walletlock
```

The `walletlock` RPC command becomes only available (in the `-help` list) after encrypting your wallet.